# how to manage OnClickListener on animated image?

Tags: android, animation, onclick, ontouchlistener

I have an animated image of a bee.
I set an `onClick` Listener to the `imageView`, and it's working, but only in native position of the `imageView`, but not when its animating.
i also tried to use `onTouchListener`, but the result is the same.

How can i make `onClick` or `onTouchListener` work while the `ImageView` is animating?

animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:shareInterpolator="true">
<scale
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:duration="8000"
    android:fromXScale="0.2"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.2"
    android:toYScale="1.5"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:pivotX="50%"/>
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:toXDelta="35"
    android:toYDelta="85"/>
<rotate
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:fromDegrees="360"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:duration="6000"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

onClick:

```
public static void onBTNClick_RidBee(Activity activity){
            bee_icon = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.bee_icon);
            bee_icon.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

onTouchListener:

```
bee_icon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d("myLogs", "clear anim bee");
                    bee_icon.clearAnimation();

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: While this may not be related to your problem, I think it is better to instantiate `bee_icon` outside the `onClickListener`.

Comment: in that case i will get NTE error

Comment: try to put image in `FrameLayout` and set `OnClickListener` on this `FrameLayout`

Comment: in this case if i set `android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent"` it doesnot metter will i click on image or on any other place on creen.
and if i set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="matwrap_contentch_parent"` it's hide some part of animation

Comment: @JohnSmith any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:fillAter="true"`. `fillAfter` controls whether the animation's ending value persists after it ends. By default, the state of the view after animation will be same as the state before the animation. for eg:suppose, before animation view's `x` position is 10, and you are translating `x` to 100, after animation the position will be still 10 not 100. But if you set `fillAfter="true"`, after animation `x` will be 100

Comment: Ok, try using `android:fillAter="true"` in `<set>` tag